# Prove that if $f$ is a linear transformation then $Df(a)(x) = f(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The question and its answer is given below

[image]

[image]

[image]

but I do not know why $r = o$, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: $r=f(x)-f(a)-f(x-a)=f(x-a-(x-a))=f(0)=0$.

Comment: Just in case that is the reason for not understanding, remember that what the second pair of parenthesis in $Df(a)(x-a)$ is, is an evaluation at $x-a$, not a multiplication by $x-a$, and that $Df(a)$ is the name of a (linear) function.

Comment: @user647486: Your argument is circular. You cannot say $r=f(x)-f(a)-f(x-a)$ because that would use $Df(a)(x-a)=f(x-a)$ which _is_ what you have to prove.

Comment: @OP: There's no particular reason for $r(x)\equiv 0$ other than the fact that along with $Df(a)(x)=f(x)$ it satisfies the definition in $(11.17)$. The $r(x)$ in that definition is the error in the approximation of $f$ with $Df$ (the linear map definition of total derivative says that $Df$ is the best linear approximation for a general map $f\colon U\subseteq\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$, and since here we have that $f$ itself is linear, $Df=f$ with the error being absolutely zero, so $r(x)\equiv 0$).

Comment: @learner There is no circularity. The definition of differential consists of the **existence** of *some* linear function $Df(a)$ for which the limit is zero. You check that for a linear function $f$, the same function used in place of $Df(a)$, the limit is zero. It is zero, because the resulting $r$ is identically zero. Thus proving existence. That is how you prove this, which is the same way that you prove existence in many cases, by explicitly showing the object who's existence you are trying to prove and checking that it satisfies the property that it should satisfy.

Comment: @user647486: From definition, $r=f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)$; your argument seems to assume $Df(a)(x-a)=f(x-a)$ which _is_ precisely what we need to _prove_.

Comment: @learner You need first to understand what is being proven first. The reason why you are so confused is because you haven't done so. The equation that you wrote thinking that that is something that needs to be proven is nothing but names. $Df(a)$ is just a name for some linear function with some property. The property, and therefore what is really the thing that needs to be proven, is the limit $\frac{r}{\|x-a\|}\to0$, where $r=f(x)-f(x)-Df(a)(x-a)$, where $Df(a)$ is just the name for some appropriately chosen function.

Comment: @user647486: Hmm, that makes sense. I stand corrected.

Comment: @learner In the case of $f$ linear, the choice for $Df(a)$ is easy. Just take $f$. But then one needs to check that it satisfies the property that $\frac{r}{\|x-a\|}\to0$. This is proven, in this case, by showing that $r$ is identically zero, by computing $r=f(x)-f(a)-f(x-a)=f(x-a-(x-a))=f(0)=0$.